# How do I download the end of a file from azure file share

Tags: c#, azure, stream, azure-storage, fileshare

This code always returns an empty string

```
        CloudFile cFile = fShare.getFile(subDir, rootDir, logFileName, AzureConstants.PATH);
        if (cFile.Exists())
        {

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                long?offset =Convert.ToInt64(cFile.Properties.Length * .8);
                long? length = Convert.ToInt64(cFile.Properties.Length * .20);


                cFile.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, offset, length);

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    return sr.ReadToEnd();// this does run and it returns an empty string ""
                }
          }    
         }
```

I'm trying to read the last 20% of the file instead of downloading the whole thing then reading the last 20%. Don't even need the last 20% just need to read the last line (its a text file). Is there something that's missing here or some other azure method I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the memory stream's position to zero before use StreamReader.

Sample code as below:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp19
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s1 = "";

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("your account", "your key"), true);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("t11");
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFile file =rootDir.GetFileReference("test.txt");

            if (file.Exists())
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    long? offset = Convert.ToInt64(file.Properties.Length * .8);
                    long? length = Convert.ToInt64(file.Properties.Length * .20);

                    file.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, offset, length);

                    //set the position of memory stream to zero
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        s1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(s1);
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("---done---");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My test file:

[image]

And the test result:
[image]